# MusicControls in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I realize that at the time of this question, Ionic 2 is still a release candidate, but I am not able to get the music controls to work in my app. I am working off the [official docs page](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/musiccontrols/).

I ran this:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-music-controls
```

and put this in my `.ts` file:

```
import {MusicControls} from 'ionic-native';
```

but I get errors in my IDE:

[image: ide error]

Additionally, where do I put this code? In my pages TS or my app TS or somewhere else:

```
MusicControls.create({ ... } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you missed a few steps like:

> npm install --save @ionic-native/music-controls

because installing the cordova plugin is not enough.

Where you put the code depends on what you are doing with it.
For example, I have a sound board app. One page of it is dedicated to playing the sounds and has controls for it. I put the code for the music controls on that page. I create the music controls on that page's constructor and destroy it when the user navigates to another page (e.g. the about page).

then it looks like:

```
import { MusicControls } from '@ionic-native/music-controls';
//...
constructor(private musicControls: MusicControls) {
    this.musicControls.create({...});
}

//...

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.musicControls.destroy();
  }
```

You can checkout the instructions on how to use the plugin here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/music-controls/

It worked well for me.
Note that you can't test this in a browser. I test it on an android device with:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Comment: I did ask this question in 2016... I'm not sure that was listed as a step back then. However, thanks!